# How to use redux with router in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I would like to ask you about how to use redux with router in React.js.

I tried to use redux with router in this code of link https://github.com/yunllvm/politequestion/tree/master/13/router-tutorial

My intention is following:

1) /src/modules is a directory for redux and redux stores a boolean flag as sign

2) use combineReducer in src/modules/index.js

3) When a user access to path '/', render Home component (App.js)

4) When Home component is rendered, if sign value of redux(src/modules/auth.js) is true, set this as false, or if sign value of redux is false, set this as true. And render sign value of redux.

But I encountered below error.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Provider
node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:10
   7 | var store = _ref.store,
   8 |     context = _ref.context,
   9 |     children = _ref.children;
> 10 | var contextValue = useMemo(function () {
     | ^  11 |   var subscription = new Subscription(store);
  12 |   subscription.onStateChange = subscription.notifyNestedSubs;
  13 |   return {
```

Below is each codes.

```
// src/index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './modules';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
// src/modules/auth.js
import {createAction, handleActions} from 'redux-actions';


const TRUE_ACTION = 'auth/TRUE';
const FALSE_ACTION = 'auth/FALSE'; 

export const tact = createAction(TRUE_ACTION);
export const fact = createAction(FALSE_ACTION);

const initialState = {
    sign:false
};

const auth = handleActions(
    {
        [TRUE_ACTION]:()=>{
            return true;
        },
        [FALSE_ACTION]:()=>{
            return false;
        }
    },
    initialState
);

export default auth;
```

```
// src/modules/index.js

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import auth from './auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

```
// src/App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';
import Profiles from './Profiles';
import HistorySample from './HistorySample';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">intro</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/profiles">profile</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/history">History example</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route path={['/about', '/info']} component={About} />
        <Route path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
        <Route path="/history" component={HistorySample} />
        <Route

          render={({ location }) => (
            <div>
              <h2>not existed.</h2>
              <p>{location.pathname}</p>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// src/Home.js

import React from 'react';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import {tact, fact} from './modules/auth';

const Home = ({sign, tact, fact}) => {

  if(sign===true){
    fact();
  }else{
    tact();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <div>{sign}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    sign:state.sign
  }),
  {
    tact,
    fact
  }

)(Home);
```

I would like to know why this TypeError has occured and how to solve this. I guess this happened as I use both redux and router together but I wasn't able to find appropriate solution.

Could you tell me what I should do more?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Yun please put some code and your requirement for clarification so that could help you

Comment: @duc mai Sorry, But I can't find how to update my question. 
So I post these links for each code. I'm sorry and thank you for your advice.
src/modules/auth.js https://github.com/yunllvm/politequestion/blob/master/13/router-tutorial/src/modules/auth.js
src/modules/index.js https://github.com/yunllvm/politequestion/blob/master/13/router-tutorial/src/modules/index.js
src/App.js https://github.com/yunllvm/politequestion/blob/master/13/router-tutorial/src/App.js
src/Home.js https://github.com/yunllvm/politequestion/blob/master/13/router-tutorial/src/Home.js

Comment: You can edit your post with the edit button at the bottom left corner of your post. Editing your post is much better, because outside links are not stable enough on the long run.

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar Thank you for your advice. I post links for each code a moment ago.
I would like to know why this TypeError has occured and how to solve this. 
I guess this happened as I use both redux and router together but I wasn't able to find appropriate solution.

Comment: please share your code content inside src/index.js

Comment: @ Peter Ambruzs Thank you for your advice. I just have updated!